# Buildroot external not entering into project source directory specified by HELLO_SITE specified in hello.mk file

Tags: buildroot

I'm trying to build a very simple hello world program using a buildroot external project.

My project structure looks like this from top level.

buildroot
hello

inside hello I have this tree

```
.
├── Config.in
├── external.desc
├── external.mk
├── hello.mk
└── src
    ├── Makefile
    └── hello.c
```

The contents of those files are as follows.

Config.in

```
config BR2_PACKAGE_HELLO
    bool "hello"
    help
        Hello world package.
        
        http://example.com
```

external.desc

```
name: HELLO
```

external.mk

```
#include $(sort $(wildcard $(BR2_EXTERNAL_HELLO_PATH)/hello/*.mk))
$(info inside $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
include $(sort $(wildcard $(BR2_EXTERNAL_HELLO_PATH)/hello.mk))
```

hello.mk

```
################################################################################
#
# hello
#
################################################################################
$(info inside $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))

HELLO_VERSION=1.0
#I don't understand why but giving site PKG_SITE below
#  makes no difference on @D variable below
#  it always points at base of project why?????
#  But if you don't define it buildroot puts this out... What gives??
#  *** HELLO_SITE cannot be empty when HELLO_SOURCE is not.  
HELLO_SITE=$(TOPDIR)/../hello/src
HELLO_SITE_METHOD=local

define HELLO_BUILD_CMDS
    $(MAKE) CC="$(TARGET_CC)" LD="$(TARGET_LD)" -C $(@D)/src
endef

define HELLO_INSTALL_TARGET_CMDS
    $(INSTALL) -D -m 0755 $(@D)/src/hello $(TARGET_DIR)/usr/bin
endef

$(eval $(generic-package))
```

src/Makefile

```
$(info inside $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))

CC = gcc

.PHONY: clean

hello: hello.c
    $(CC) -o '$@' '$<'
clean:
    rm hello
```

src/hello.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("hello");
}
```

Inside the buildroot directory I have a local.mk with this line in it

```
HELLO_OVERRIDE_SRCDIR = ../hello
```

From the buildroot folder I run

```
make BR2_EXTERNAL="$(pwd)/../hello" myprj_defconfig
echo 'BR2_PACKAGE_HELLO=y' >> .config
make hello-rebuild all
```

The hello executable is built.  BUT ... the HELLO_SITE=$(TOPDIR)/../hello/src in hello.mk is not taking effect.  See comments in hello.mk.  The @D variable will not point at what is defined by HELLO_SITE.  Though if I remove HELLO_SITE completely buildroot spits out the message in the comments.  Also if I assign HELLO_SITE a garbage name it doesn't matter it builds anyhow and does not try to enter the garbage path.  It's building with the files above because I appended /src to @D in hello.mk.  In the examples I have found online this should not be necessary because HELLO_SITE should make buildroot enter the src folder to run the Makefile.  For me this is not working.

From everything I see in google searches and buildroot docs HELLO_SITE should be respected but it's not.

Anybody see what I am doing wrong?

I am using buildroot 2023.02-1.0.

Thank you.

Comment: When I mention above that assigning HELLO_SITE a garbage name it doesn't matter.  I meant if I assign it a garbage path or value.

Comment: If I replace @D in hello.mk with HELLO_SITE everything works.  After removing appended /src from @D.

Comment: From debugging it appears that buildroot defaults to hello-custom.tar.gz as HELLO_SOURCE if it is not specified which causes error when HELLO_SITE is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

A package must be in a directory with the same name as the package, so in this case `hello`. In other words, the files should be organized like this:

```
.
├── Config.in
├── external.desc
├── external.mk
└── hello
    ├── Makefile
    ├── hello.c
    └── hello.mk
```

(You would typically also put a `Config.in` in the `hello` directory, but that's not strictly required.)

In the `hello.mk` file, you shouldn't use `$(TOPDIR) because that points to the Buildroot directory and it's hard to keep track of where the Buildroot directory is relative to the` hello`directory. Instead, use`$(BR2_EXTERNAL_HELLO_PATH)`, like this (assuming the above directory organisation, with` Makefile`in the`hello`subdirectory and no`src` subdirectory.

```
################################################################################
#
# hello
#
################################################################################
HELLO_SITE = $(BR2_EXTERNAL_HELLO_PATH)/hello
HELLO_SITE_METHOD = local

define HELLO_BUILD_CMDS
    $(MAKE) CC="$(TARGET_CC)" LD="$(TARGET_LD)" -C $(@D)
endef

define HELLO_INSTALL_TARGET_CMDS
    $(INSTALL) -D -m 0755 $(@D)hello $(TARGET_DIR)/usr/bin
endef

$(eval $(generic-package))
```

Comment: I tried this and it still didn't work.  The @D always points at the top of the package.

Comment: Thank you for replying.  I tried this and it still didn't work.  I changed the external.mk to include $(sort $(wildcard $(BR2_EXTERNAL_HELLO_PATH)/hello/*.mk)). The @D always points at the top of the package.  The debug shows it went inside the innermost hello.  But still it completely disregards HELLO_SITE and @D still is the top of the package.  The output looks like this.  inside /home/mjones/buildroot/hello/external.mk.  inside /home/mjones/buildroot/hello/hello/hello.mk.  It -C into top of package still and no Makefile found.  Disregards HELLO_SITE completely.

Comment: TOPDIR points to the buildroot directory. You probably shouldn't use it in your .mk file; instead use BR2_EXTERNAL_HELLO_PATH. I'll update the answer accordingly.